# Synchronized writing and reading in file with not join object variable of file

Tags: java, multithreading, file, concurrency, file-locking

I'm trying to implement threads concurrency in Java. It consists of trying to write in the file for the last time. There are two threads: `A` - which is creating a file and checking if the right line is in the file and `B` - which is searching for a file and trying to rewrite the file with a “good” line. The “winner” thread must have string in a file. To do it thread checks if file has their line, file has only one line. The threads have only file path.

```
public class A implements Runnable {
private File file;
private Thread t;

public A(String patch,String fileName)
{
    t = new Thread(this);
    CreateFile(patch, fileName);
    //t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedReader reader;
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
            if (reader.readLine().charAt(0) == 'B') {
                System.out.println("A try took file: " + file.getName());
                write();
            } else {
                System.out.println("A took file: " + file.getName());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File read A" + e.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File read A"+e.toString());
        }
    }
}


private void write() {
    try {
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
        printWriter.println("A took file: " + file.getName());
        System.out.println("A took file: " + file.getName());
        printWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File write A");
    }
}

public File CreateFile(String patch,String fileName) {
    File file = new File(patch,fileName+".txt");
    try {
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
        printWriter.println("A took file: " + file.getName());
        System.out.println("A took file: " + file.getName());
        printWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File create A");
    }
    return file;
}
}

public class B implements Runnable {
private File file;
private Thread t;

public B(String patch,String fileName)
{
    t = new Thread(this);
    //t.setDaemon(true);
    FindFile(patch, fileName);
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedReader reader;
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
            if (reader.readLine().charAt(0) == 'A') {
                System.out.println("B try took file: " + file.getName());
                write();
            } else {
                System.out.println("B took file: " + file.getName());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File read B" + e.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File read B"+e.toString());
        }
    }
}


private void write() {
    try {
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
        printWriter.println("B took file: " + file.getName());
        System.out.println("B took file: " + file.getName());
        printWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File write B");
    }
}

public File FindFile(String patch,String fileName) {
    File file= null;
    File folder = new File(patch);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    BufferedReader reader;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        file = listOfFiles[i];
        if (file.getName().equals(fileName + ".txt")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return file;
}
}
```

I want to synchronize in some way access to the file in threads. In my code I have `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I use `readLine()`, so I think this is because threads don’t have synchronized access to the file (after every finished operation file must have one line). I can’t use synchronized method or block, because threads don’t have joint variable of the file. Is there some way of making synchronized writing and reading in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ReentrantReadWriteLock** to synchronize. Parse the same lock for synchronize both A and B. Here I have modified B. You can do the same for A as well.

```
public static class B implements Runnable {
        private File file;
        private Thread t;
        private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock;

        public B(String patch,String fileName, ReentrantReadWriteLock lock)
        {
            t = new Thread(this);
            this.lock = lock;
            //t.setDaemon(true);
            FindFile(patch, fileName);
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader reader;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    lock.readLock().lock();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
                    if (reader.readLine().charAt(0) == 'A') {
                        lock.readLock().unlock();
                        lock.writeLock().lock();
                        System.out.println("B try took file: " + file.getName());
                        write();
                        lock.writeLock().unlock();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("B took file: " + file.getName());
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("File read B" + e.toString());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("File read B"+e.toString());
                }
            }
        }


        private void write() {
            try {
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
                printWriter.println("B took file: " + file.getName());
                System.out.println("B took file: " + file.getName());
                printWriter.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("File write B");
            }
        }

        public File FindFile(String patch,String fileName) {
            File file= null;
            File folder = new File(patch);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            BufferedReader reader;
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                file = listOfFiles[i];
                if (file.getName().equals(fileName + ".txt")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return file;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't understand me. I don't want to change a constructor. I ask if I can synchronize threads without common object (`ReentrantReadWriteLock`) only to create it in threads. For example, for plural pairs of threads in your variant I must create also plural the same objects of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, or if starts of threads from different classes I can't use the same lock object.

Comment: Then you can use the following logic
String s; 
if (((s=reader.readLine())!= null) && s.startsWith("A") ){
//your execution
}